# Mule:Expression filter not working

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Having a requirment to filter a message if some session variable is false or true

flow.xml

```
<spring:beans>
      <spring:bean id="serviceBean" class="com.uidai.ServiceBean"/>
    </spring:beans>

    <flow name="messagefilterFlow1" doc:name="messagefilterFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="D:/sample" />
        <invoke object-ref="serviceBean" method="enrichFilter" doc:name="Invoke" methodArguments="#[sessionVars],#[message]"/>
        <logger level="INFO" message="#[sessionVars['filter']]" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <!--<message-property-filter pattern="#[sessionVars['filter']]=true" caseSensitive="true" doc:name="Message Property"/>-->
         <expression-filter  expression="#[sessionVars['filter']]" doc:name="Expression"/> 
        <file:outbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="D:/sample2"/>
    </flow>
```

Service bean method

```
public void enrichFilter(MessagePropertyMapContext mapContext, MessageContext messageContext){
        mapContext.put("filter", false);
        System.out.println("mapContext" + mapContext);
        System.out.println("message Context:::" + messageContext);
    }

Reading a file from inbound and setting a session variable in spring bean method. Wanted to filter the message on basis of filter  value so that if filter value is true outbound file is not written and message is filtered. Even if filter value is true or false a lock is hold on file by inbound endpoint and processing stops.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce on 3.5.2.

I suggest you to put a breakpoint in ExpressionFilter.class in the method accept() to realize why the line `return muleContext.getExpressionManager().evaluateBoolean(expr, message, nullReturnsTrue, !nullReturnsTrue);` is always returning `false` for you.

Another suggestion to leverage the lesser amount of magic possible is to prepend return to your filter expression and/or implement a java filter by implementing the Filter interfance and then using the [custom-filter](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Custom+Filter) element.

Comment: It works only for outbound property and not for session if expression="#[header:filter=true]" but still if a message is filtered file:inbound hold lock on the file and does nt release the lock. Even it doesnt throw an exception when message is filtered so that i can handle it in catch exception strategy

Comment: Issue resolved after wrappring expression filter in a message filter                       <message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true">
            <expression-filter  expression="#[header:filter=true]" doc:name="Expression" />
         </message-filter>